# How do I raise the ping of one of my ports on my Linksys Cisco WRT160N v2 Router?

Tags: router, connection, performance-tuning

I'm a real newbie when it comes to computers, internet, networking, etc. but I'm an avid gamer. And I play a game (on my PS3) which plays best at a higher pings (slower speeds) for some reason beyond my understanding.
So after a LOT of searching I've found how to access my router settings: I found my 'Default Gateway IP-thing and typed it into my URL bar and entered my router password.
...this is as far as I've gotten.

From here, I just want to make only ONE of my 4 ports have a high ping (slow speed) so I can plug my ethernet cord from my PS3 to that port when I'm playing that specific game.
I don't want to tone-down or negatively effect any other port or slow the speed of anything using the WiFi... only this one port.

How do I go about doing this... in layman's terms?

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is [cheating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheating_in_online_games#Artificial_lag). Please don't help this person.

Comment: How is it cheating?
The game was altered and the suggested fix is what I'm asking about how to do.
I'm not asking how to switch my connection back and forth during gameplay... that WOULD be cheating and far beyond my technical knowledge. Not to mention not worth the effort over a video game.

Comment: @Ken Artificial lag is considered cheating in online games. What you perceive as the game playing "best" is it doing a poor job for compensating for lag in a way that you find beneficial. Forcing the game to poorly compensate for lag to your benefit is cheating.